# List inside list in Java

Tags: java, sql

this is my very first time using Java. I need help on assigning a list into a list based on an attribute unique value.
I am creating an object from an SQL table called `Student`, the attributes are `ID`, `NAME`, and `COUNTRY`

```
package Data;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Oracle.DBConnection;

public class Students {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     DBConnection.OpenConnection();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT ORDER BY COUNTRY";
     Student[] students = DBConnection.ExecuteQuery(query);
     DBConnection.CloseConnection();

     }
}
```

Now I have object students, Is there any way I can group the students object based on unique city and create a list that contains these objects?
The list will be like:

```
List = [object1, object2, object3,etc]
```

and each object has records of same `COUNTRY`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the JavaScript question tag? I've removed it since the question doesn't appear to have anything to do with this language. If I'm wrong, please inform me.

Comment: Does this: `Student[] students = DBConnection.ExecuteQuery(query);` compile?

Comment: Assuming your `ORDER BY` clause is working, then the `Student[]` array you are already getting back should have students sorted by country.  Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking at a map, more specifically a `Map<String, Set<Student>>` instead.
The array you're getting back should already be ordered because that's what you put in your query, but if you then want to organize and use your data further, you can transform this list into a map which is a data structure that is more useful to you.

For example (in Java 8) with something like this:

```
List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(students);
Map<String, Set<Student>> mapByCountry = studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getCountry(), Collectors.toSet()));
```

(this is assuming that your country field is a String)

Now you can access students per country by just asking the map.

```
Set<Student> studentsInMyCountry = mapByCountry.get("TheBestCountryInTheWorld");
```

Of course there are also ways to transform the original list into a list of lists like you asked, but that would be less useful because then you still don't know which country the students in a sublist belong to except by evaluating that again.

Comment: Yes, the object students has been ordered. But I want to "slice" the student object to become many objects based on the unique value of country

Comment: @BernandoPurba Sorry I was still working on the code part ;) should be clear now.

Comment: @BernandoPurba: please improve your question so that you're showing real code so that your question is useful to future visitors.